# Is having my essays proofread inappropriate?

Tags: coursework, cheating, proofreading

English is not my first language. My pronunciation and grammar are not perfect. I tried to write an essay in my own words. After that I asked for help from my friend to proofread the essay.

She told me I’m cheating to have someone help in this way, because when I submit the essay, the words and grammar will be different than what I wrote (the first version of the essay has too much incorrect grammar). That’s why she will report me.

I don’t think I am wrong because the tutorials in every school are still using proofreaders to help students.
The instructor just said that we should be using sources from class to do the essay, and to cite any other sources. The policies don’t say that I can’t use proofreading.
So what do I have to do? Will the report affect me in the future?

Comment: Much depends on the topic. If it is English language/literature/translation, the skill of perfecting a language is what is being co-assessed. In Natural Sciences, probably less so. Ask your instructor if proofreading is ok and to which extent, and remove all doubts.

Answer (score 2):

The only correct answer is to **ask your instructor.**

As a general rule though, **proofreading is encouraged.** In the professional world, proofreading (or copy editing) is a normal part of scholarship because the goal is to make the final paper as neat and polished as possible.

Sometimes it is appropriate to cite help you have had with a paper. If there is legitimate contribution and collaboration, this is often done with giving co-authorship. If a specific idea is used, this is often in the form of a footnote. **For proofreading,** this is sometimes in the form of an acknowledgement; sometimes proofreaders are not recognized at all.

Unless your instructor specifically prohibited proofreading, **this is not cheating/plagiarism.**

Answer (score 0):

I assume in ELL courses it's your job to proofread, re-edit and re-edit more until it's polished. So put in more work to fine-tune your essays yourself. Even native English speakers need to do this. Edit your essay over and over again until you think it's the best you can do (or the best with the time available).

For the specific situation, perhaps ask the instructor yourself (hopefully before your "friend" reports you). If you were in the wrong, perhaps suggest an additional assignment to replace or at least slightly improve your standing in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case in the past that's not a problem because I will always have my classmates, friends, relative or parents and sometimes my teachers proof read my essays.
Maybe now some teachers would punish there student but in the past your teacher would praise you for it.

Or as an alternative ask first if its okay or not to ask somebody else proof read your essays .